# Problema com escrever em textbox escondida com Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando escrever em uma textbox e clicar em um botão (esses elementos estão inicialmente escondidos na página) utilizando selenium (com Java), mas não consigo achar o elemento, já tentei procurar por name, ID, tagname, className, XPath, não consigo manipular de maneira alguma.

Segue print da tela com inspecionar elementos ativo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que acontece é que para essa textbox e botão aparecerem na tela eu preciso clicar no botão requerer (até essa parte eu consigo):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí os elementos que comentei ficam ativos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No código abaixo eu peguei a quantidade de elementos que eu encontro na página que tenham o mesmo id, name, tagName, className ou XPath da textbox que quero manipular (as 2 primeiras linhas é para apertar o botão requerer, essa parte está funcionando):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, em todas as formas de manipular a textbox retornam que não existe tal elemento (a não ser className, mas desses 10 elementos encontrados nenhum é a textbox que quero manipular, já testei um por um).

Como essa página faz parte de um portal local da empresa em que trabalho, não adianta eu passar um link para verificarem, por isso mandei diversos prints.

Alguém sabe de alguma forma de lidar com esses elementos hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a classe `JavascriptExecutor` para executar um código Javascript na própria página, e deixar o elemento visível:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('_Justificativa').style.visibility = 'visible'");
```

Pode setar o valor:

```
String texto = "Ola Mundo!";
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('_Justificativa').value = '" + texto + "'");
```

E caso necessário, pode clicar no elemento também:

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('_Justificativa').click()");
```

Comment: Caio, esse código seria para manipular o IE né? Você saberia fazer isso manipulando o chrome? Qualquer coisa tento traduzir meu código pra manipular o IE e testar essa idéia.

Comment: Tentei utilizando esse codigo:
WebElement txb =driver.findElement(By.name("_Justificativa"));   
      
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", txb);

Mas na linha que tento encontrar o elemento dá erro e o programa para.

Comment: Esse código funciona pra qualquer navegador, creio eu! Eu mesmo uso sempre o Firefox e nunca tive problema, não é para ter dor de cabeça com o Chrome também.

Em relação a esse seu erro, ele se dá pois o elemento está escondido, e o Selenium tenta encontrar o WebElement mesmo assim.
O que imagino que seja viável e funcione, é o que eu publiquei na resposta, que seria uma "injeção" javascript. Tenta usar exatamente como tá ali, e me dá uma resposta pra saber se deu certo!

Comment: Agora eu consegui. Percebi que a textbox e o botão estavam dentro de um iFrame, e ao pesquisar na internet vi que tinha que usar "driver.switchTo().frame(0);" para depois conseguir escrever nele. O javascript dava erro porque não conseguia encontrar nenhum elemento com o nome ou id que eu passava.

Comment: Entendi. Ótimo que conseguiu resolver! Você também consegue mudar para o frame passando o ID dele como argumento, caso precise, e por questões de facilitar a visualização também.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. No meu caso não daria certo passar por ID ou por Name porque esses identificadores não são fixos na minha iFrame, cada vez que rodo o programa eles mudam, por isso tive que optar pelo índice.

Answer (score 0):

Agora consegui resolver.
Para os próximos que tiverem o mesmo problema que eu:

Após ir subindo no inspecionar elemento notei que toda aquela div que englobava a caixa de texto e o botão era um iFrame, vi nesse site (https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html) que precisava dar os seguintes comandos:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);

        driver.findElement(By.name("_Justificativa")).sendKeys("teste");
```

No caso o "0" do "driver.switchTo().frame(0)" é o índice do meu iFrame, caso tenha mais de um iFrame na página será necessário verificar qual é o que você precisa manipular, pode usar o comando "driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe").size());" para identificar a quantidade de iFrames na página.

Pra mim isso resolveu.